# How to determine that the Plot has been rendered by Core-Plot

Tags: ios, core-plot

In our project we are using CorePlot to display some graphs, they use CPTXYPlot and we are displaying some scatter plots. This is all well and we actually like the plotting library a lot. Big thanks to Eric Skroch and team for the great work they've done putting it together!

Since we are displaying a lot of things on the view we had to push most of the work on a separate thread. While these things are completed we display an activity indicator. In order to know when to hide the activity indicator one of the things that we need to know is if the plotting has completed. But when our code block for updating the plot has completed the plotting is still not done but execution completes. As a result our activity indicator is prematurely hidden.

Here is what we are doing. The plot itself is created on the main thread (I've read that it must be created there).

On the other thread we are removing all plots from the graph, re-calculating the data and then adding the plots again. Something like:

```
Graph.removePlotWithIdentifier(_baselineScatterPlotIdentifier)
for i in 0..<comparedPlotsData.count {
    Graph.removePlotWithIdentifier("\(_comparedScatterPlotIdentifierPrefix)\(i)")
}

// Data update goes here

Graph.addPlot(drawBaselineScatterPlot())
for i in 0..<comparedPlotsData.count {
    Graph.addPlot(drawComparedScatterPlot(i))
}
```

In our case this code completes several seconds before we actually see the plot updated. And just one clarification that the maximum number of scatter plots is less than 10.

Can you please give us an idea what we are missing or what we are doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a plot delegate and implement the [`-didFinishDrawing:`](http://core-plot.github.io/iOS/protocol_c_p_t_plot_delegate-p.html#af68ded0e9746646e581c32b1aa999573) method. The plot that finished a draw cycle is passed as a parameter to the method so you can keep track of which ones are finished.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you very much for the great work you've done and you are continuing to do!